# jquery validate plugin can't access label in the success callback

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that i'm trying to use the jquery validate plugin. My problem is that i can't access the label in the success callback. I can get `label.attr('for')`, but when i try `label.attr('id')`, or `label.html()`, i get undefined.

Here's my validate call:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#personal_info').validate({
                rules: {
                    LastName: "required",
                    Age: "required"
                },
                messages: {
                    LastName: "",
                    Age: ""
                },
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    console.log('element.attr = '+element.attr('name'));
                    if(element.attr('name') == 'Age') {
                            console.log('element = '+element.parents().siblings('label').html());
                            element.parents().siblings('label').removeClass('highlight').addClass('warning');
                    }                                       
                    //error.insertBefore(element.parent().children("br"));
                },

                // specifying a submitHandler prevents the default submit, good for the demo
                submitHandler: function() {
                    document.personal_info.submit();
                },
                validClass: "checkmark",
                // set this class to error-labels to indicate valid fields
                success: function(label) {
                    console.log('the label for = '+label.attr('for'));
                    console.log('the label id = '+label.attr('id'));
                }   
            });
        });
</script>
```

Here's a piece of my html:

```
<label for="Age" id="age18" class="highlight">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Are you at least 18 years of age?</label>
       <table id="OnlineAppWizard_InputAge18" border="0">
             <tr>
                 <td>
                     <input id="Age18_yes" type="radio" name="Age" value="Yes"  <?
                         if ($Age18 == "Yes") {
                               print "checked";
                         }
                      ?>/>
                     <label for="Age18_yes">Yes</label>
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     <input id="Age18_no" type="radio" name="Age" value="No" <?
                         if ($Age18 == "No") {
                                print "checked";
                         } ?>/>
                     <label for="Age18_no">No</label>
                 </td>
             </tr>
         </table>
```

When i click on one of the radio buttons, this is what appears in the firebug console:the

```
the label for = Age
the label id = undefined
```

You can see from the html snippet that the label tag with the "for" attribute of "Age", also has an "id" attribute of "age18"

Comment: Can you provide the link to the jquery validation library ?

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation. I'm on an older version, but i tried updating to the latest version and it didn't help.

Comment: Can you show some working example where we can see this problem in action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `label` parameter passed to the `success` callback is not the label you think it is. The jQuery Validation plugin generates error labels for each element to display error messages. It is this generated label that is passed to the `success` callback. You can see this by adding `console.log(label);` as the first line of the callback. It will return the following:

```
[<label for=​"Age" generated=​"true" class=​"error" style=​"display:​ inline;​ ">​</label>​]
```

FYI, that label is created in the `showLabel` method of the validator. It is also the same element that is passed as the `error` parameter of the `errorPlacement` method. Generally, the `error` element would be appended to the form element that caused the error (i.e., failed to validate).

To access the original label from the `success` callback, you will need a more direct approach.

One solution, and very specific to this particular label, is to simply access it by it's ID, e.g.

```
if(label.attr('for') === 'Age') {
    $('#age18')...    // do something to the label
}
```

A more generic solution would be:

```
$('#personal_info').children('[for="' + label.attr('for') + '"]')...  // do something to label
```

I have included both solutions in the live demo linked below.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhjet/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. I used the specific solution that you posted.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I did it. To be able to place a custom image next to the input box and to remove it and to change border colors of the input box.

```
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>error handling</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/screen.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-validation-1.13.1/lib/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-validation-1.13.1/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{
$("#someForm").validate({
        rules: 
        {
            param1: {required: true, minlength: 3, maxlength: 15},
            param2: {required: true, minlength: 3, maxlength: 15}
        },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) 
    {
            element.attr("style","border-color: red");
            element.parent('div').append( '<div id="'+element.attr('id')+"img"+'" class="errorValidationIcon"><a href="#" class="errorValidationTooltip"><img src="img/redError.png" class="errorValidationIcon"/><span><img class="callout" src="img/callout.gif" /><strong></strong><br /></span> </a></div> '); 
            error.appendTo('strong'); 
    },
    success: function(label) 
        {
            if (label.attr('for') === 'param1') 
            {
                $('#param1img').remove();
                $('#param1').attr("style", "border-color: rgb(83,103,141)");
            }
            if (label.attr('for') === 'param2') 
            {
                $('#param2img').remove();
                $('#param2').attr("style", "border-color: rgb(83,103,141)");
            }
        }
    }); 
});

</script>
</head>


<body>
<div id="layoutCenter">
<form id="someForm" action="#">
    <div>
    <div>Register</div>

    <div>
        <div>Blah</div>  
        <div ><div >Parameter<div>*</div></div><div ><input name="param1" id="param1" type="text" /></div></div>
        <div ><div >OID<div>*</div></div><div ><input name="param2" id="param2" type="text" /></div></div>
    </div>

    </div>
</form>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```